# Add table to Visual Studio 2013 but it restarts

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio-2013

1. Using Visual Studio 2013 ultimate
2. Add new window application
3. Add **new service based database**
4. Click on add new table.
5. Visual Studio **restarts** every time

How to fix this problem?

Comment: not fixed after repair.

Comment: its the only issue with your VS 2013. Install other version and try.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to disable all extensions running in Visual Studio: [How to: Add or Remove Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff852054(v=vs.120).aspx)

If your problem persists, you can contact Microsoft to request support for Visual Studio: [Visual Studio Support](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/)